# Prove that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a set and $A\subseteq X$. We can define $\tau=\{Z\subseteq X:A \subseteq Z\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$. Show that $\tau$ is an topology over $X$.

Try the following:

**1.** Note that $\emptyset\in \tau$ by definition, and how $X \subseteq X$, if $Z=X$, we can see that $X\in \tau$.

**2.** Let $\{C_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ an arbitrary collection  of $\tau$.

*case 1:* If $C_{i}=\emptyset$, for all $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i}=\emptyset \in \tau$.

*case 2:* If $C_{i}\neq\emptyset$, for some $i \in I$, then $A \subseteq C_{i}$ (for all $i\in I$), so note that

$$A \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} A \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i}$$

So $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i}$, but it's $\bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i}\in \tau$

**3.** In this case, I think it is similar, two cases, but when $C_{i}\neq \emptyset$ for all $i\in\{1, \dots, n\}$ I am not sure how to conclude.

That is a small approximation of the result, is there something wrong? any help? I appreciate it!

Comment: Case 2: "If $C_i\ne\emptyset$ for some $i\in I$, then $A\subseteq C_i$ for all $i\in I$." : FALSE

Comment: "and **since** $A \subseteq X$, we can see that $X \in \tau$"

Comment: Note also that the space $(X, \tau)$ as defined is homeomorphic to the quotient space derived from $X$ under the discrete topology by collapsing the set $A$ to a single point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finishing off, if $C_{1}, C_{2} \in \tau$ and neither are empty, then $A \subseteq C_{1} \cap C_{2}$ as $A \subseteq C_{1},C_{2}$ by definition. Hence, $C_{1} \cap C_{2} \in \tau$. If either were empty, then $C_{1} \cap C_{2} = \emptyset \in \tau$ aswell.

Aswell as that, theres a slight error in (2) in case 2. If $C_{i} \neq \emptyset$ for some $i$, then $A \subseteq C_{i}$ for all $i$ for which $C_{i} \neq \emptyset$, not $A \subseteq C_{i}$ for all $i$. $A$ is still in the union of all $C_{i}$'s as $A$ is contained in every non-empty $C_{i}$.